# I am having troubles with a 404-error message from Django. It says "No location found matching the query"

Tags: python, django, django-templates

So I am taking the One Month Python course online and I am having some issues. The thing is that my general expression `(?P<pk>\d+)/detail/$` does not seem to work hence the 404-message.

Here is my code:
main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = patterns ('',
    # blah blah
    # blah blah blah
    # Blaaaahhh

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'', include('core.urls')),
)
```

core/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import core.views as coreviews

urlpatterns = patterns ('',

    url(r'^$', coreviews.LandingView.as_view()),
    url(r'location/$', coreviews.LocationListView.as_view()),
    url(r'location/(?P<pk>\d+)/detail/$', coreviews.LocationDetailView.as_view()),

)
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
import core.models as coremodels
# Create your views here.

class LandingView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base/index.html"


class LocationListView(ListView):
    model = coremodels.Location
    template_name = 'location/list.html'


class LocationDetailView(DetailView):
    model = coremodels.Location
    template_name = 'location/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'location'
```

I have already created five locations using the Django admin site: https://gyazo.com/1db0b35fafdacb3d4991fbea3990ee61

Here is the actual error message:
[image]

Comment: Is this a typo in your expression in the question or you forgot to open the bracket?

Comment: Please post your complete urls.py, and the url that is causing the 404.

Comment: It is a Typo, Wtower.

Comment: Also post your main `urls.py` please.

Comment: @Alasdair, I am developing locally, but this is the one: http://127.0.0.1:8000/location/1/detail/

Comment: of course, just a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message `"No location found matching the query"` suggests that the url pattern is correct, but there is no location with `pk=1` in the database. You probably deleted it.

Try a different url e.g. `/location/2/detail/` for a primary key that definitely exists.

You can find a primary key by doing something like `Location.objects.first().id` in the shell, or simply clicking on a location in the Django admin, and looking at the url.

Comment: I am getting a new error now having entered a primary key that defintely exits ... Invalid block tag: 'endfor', expected 'endblock'

Comment: It works fine now! I had messed up with some block tags. Sorry for the inconvenience, and especially thanks to @Alasdair!